# Expand $\ln(\sqrt[3]{x^2})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I am to expand $\ln(\sqrt[3]{x^2})$. The textbook solutions page say it should be $\frac{2}{3}\ln(x)$.

I gave it a try but suspect I went wrong further up in my calculations. I got $\frac{1}{2}\ln(x)$.

My working:
$$\ln(\sqrt[3]{x^2})$$
$$\ln(x^\frac{1}{2})$$

(Is there a rule for the nth mth root? I forget? Can I simplify $\sqrt[3]{x^2}$?. Here I thought that if it's a 3rd root of $x^2$ then I still have one more root to go, assuming they cancel out to two powers?)

And then
$$\frac{1}{2}\ln(x)$$

How can I arrive at $\frac{2}{3}\ln(x)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your suspicion is correct.  That is the third root of $x^2$, which is $(x^2)^\frac13=x^\frac23$.  So that's how it turns to $\frac23\ln x$.

Comment: The $n$'th root of $x^m$ is $x^m/n$.  Breaking it into steps, the $n$'th root of any $x$ is $x^\frac1n$ and $(a^x)^y=a^{xy}$.

Comment: Fixing the typo in the above comment: The $n^{th}$ root of $x^m$ is $x^{m/n}$.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to know that $\sqrt[n]{x} = x^{1/n}.$  This makes sense because

$$x^{1/3}x^{1/3}x^{1/3} = x^{1/3+1/3+1/3} = x^1.$$

Answer (score 2):

In general, $$\sqrt[n]{x^m} = x^{m/n},$$ and hence $$\ln\left(\sqrt[n]{x^m}\right) = \ln x^{m/n} = \frac{m}{n}\ln x.$$

Answer (score 2):

You may unwrap it as $\ln\sqrt[3]{x^2}=\tfrac13\ln(x^2)=\tfrac132\ln x=\tfrac23\ln |x|$ for $x\in\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$. For $x>0$, we can drop the mod signs. More generally, $\ln\sqrt[N]{x^m}=\tfrac1N\ln(x^M)=\tfrac{M}{N}\ln x$ works for $x>0$, while we get $\tfrac{M}{N}\ln|x|$ for $x\ne0$ if $M$ is even.